# How to check if the tubing of a portable split air conditioner is twisted

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Last year I bought [this portable split air conditioner](https://uk.trotec.com/shop/pac-4600-split-air-conditioner.html), Trotec PAC 4600.

The people who delivered it made an awful mess: they put it upside down in the box(!).

Unfortunately I did not know that, they just left the pallet in front of my place, I carried it up to my flat as it was, without changing the orientation of the box, and I when I opened it (from the top, of course) I saw the wheels of the indoor unit and the bottom of the outdoor unit looking at me...

At that point I must not have been thinking very clearly, because instead of just gently inclining the box on its side and somehow put the whole thing the right way up as a single block, I decided to take out the two units one after the other.

Trouble is, I am not sure if in doing that I somehow twisted the tubing connecting the two units...

**Do you know of any way I could check that and fix it, which wouldn't require fully disassembling it ?**

More information, if it can help:

What I observed was that the tubing feels quite rigid, and when I lift the outdoor unit, it feels awkward, it only 'wants' to go to certain places and it stays stuck at a specific angle.
That's what makes me suspect that it could be twisted: then the rigidity I experience could be due to that.
I would expect such a connecting tubing to be relatively free to move, indeed as long as it stays in a neat line departing from the two units, as the instructions say you should keep them.

My parents have a much older but similar model, where however the plastic surrounding the tubing is thin and flat, so you can see very clearly where the tubing inside is, you could not possibly twist it and not know you did.
With this one, the tubing is encased in this thick round thing, so it could be twisted N times in there, causing the behaviour I see.

I used this airco for several months last year and this year, and from my point of view it seemed to work well.
This year I had already put it away, thinking the hot weather was over, and just now I reinstalled it again because they are forecasting very high temperatures for next week.
And in doing that I noticed that the outdoor unit did not want to go anymore to the position it was until recently... and I heard some worrying noises when I was moving it...

Given the cost of this stuff, I really wouldn't want to break it, or to make it work in a way that can damage it in the long term.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You put it in it's current position so you should be able to orient it differently.  After that, which position does everything seem to be best in?

Comment: Yes I am able to orient it differently, but the problem is that whenever I lift and move the outdoor unit, I feel a lot of rigidity and 'pulling', so I try not to force it, and leave it in the position that feels less strained. Normally, I would have expected to be able to place the outdoor unit 'parallel' to the indoor one, facing the other way of course, with the connecting thingy in a straight line between them. Instead no, it stays straight for about 1 m coming out of the indoor unit, and then it bends left, and the outdoor unit is resting at a ~45 degrees angle vs the indoor one. Weird.

Comment: That's why I suspect that during the unboxing I imparted a twist to the tubing inside, and that the 'pull' is due to the resulting mechanical strain. Cannot be healthy for the machine, can it? In principle I could lay the indoor unit flat to the floor, and rotate the outdoor unit until it feels less strained, but that sounds very risky to me. If only they had made the tubing case flat, at least I could see what it's like in there...